# External CSS files causing problems to images

Tags: html, css

This is NetBeans. I have tried to include an external CSS file but when used externally the images all get really enlarged. Whereas my I use the same styling within the html file using internal styling the images are of correct ratio.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #080808;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.inner header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 90px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ededed;
}

.header link {
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#su {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 90px;
}

#l {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 600px;
}

.banner-image {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background: url(image/intro-bg_1.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.inner-banner-image {
  padding-top: 12%;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.banner-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-bottom: 6%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 12%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  max-width: 660px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #ac2925;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  width: 30%;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.caption {
  color: #000;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lifestyle Store</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner header">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="">Lifestyle Store</a>
      </div>
      <div class="header link">
        <div id="su">
          <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
        <div id="l">
          <a href="#">Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="banner-image">
      <div class="inner-banner-image ">
        <div class="banner-content">
          <h1>We sell lifestyle</h1>
          <p>Flat 40% OFF on premium brands</p>
          <form>
            <a href="#" class="button">Shop Now</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="items">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="image/camera.jpg" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Cameras</h2>
          <p>Choose among the best from the world</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="image/watch.jpg" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Watches</h2>
          <p>Original watches from the best brands</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="image/shirt.jpg" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Shirts</h2>
          <p>Our exquisite collection of shirts</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Copyright © Lifestyle Store. All Rights Reserved | Contact Us: +91 90000 00000</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use developer tools to see if there are any 404 errors when loading the external stylesheet. If you see 404 then it means that the resource is not available in the referred location.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "internal styling"? Give some code as an example. And please try to break up your code block into separate blocks for each file--and remove all of the extraneous code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the CSS file correctly in this line? Try dragging and dropping the file directly into the HTML to ensure the location and name is correct.

```
href="assignment1/public_html/style.css"
```

Edit:

The current link you have is saying that you have the index.html file outside of the 'assignment1' folder. If you have your HTML file inside 'public_html' then the stylesheet link should be the following.

```
href="style.css"
```

Comment: i have tried both :/ with style.css no styles get applied

Comment: Have you put the <link> tag in the head of your website? I can't see it in the code you've updated your original post with.